# How to send a File using TCP socket Programming from 64 bit PC to 32 bit PC?

Tags: java, tcp

*Hi everyone,*

My Question is Simple: I tried many times to send a File using tcp socket in java but i had alawys used the local host 127.0.0.1 as an ip destination address of the server. i want now to send a file from my 64bit PC ( client ) to another a 32 bit PC (server) with some new ip address :

***_ Should i run the server java program first on the 32 bit pc then the client java program on the 64bit pc in order to achieve my goal ? or can i run both programs in only one of the pcs ?***

***_ is the windows bit version affects the sending operation ?***

if someone please could help me with some info or video i will be thankful.

*Thanks in Advance.*

Answer (score 0):

The java classes themselves are platform independent.  That's part of the whole point of Java, so the Windows version doesn't matter.  The client code connects to the IP address of the machine running the server code, which presumably is where you want the file to go.  If that's a different box, then use that IP.  If it's the same box, then use 127.0.0.1 but the server code has to be running for the client to connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Duston. My main Question was should i run the server code first in my second pc then the client code on my first pc or running both of the codes on the same machine in order to transfer the file ? thanks again

Comment: Typically the server code is started on the destination box and then sits quietly waiting for a connection.  Typically the server code runs on the box where you want the files to wind up.  While the server code is quietly waiting for a connection, you start the client code to send the file.  Typically the server code will then receive the file and store it.  After the client closes the connection, typically the server code will resume quietly waiting for a connection.  Does that clarify my answer?